# Problema para actualizar una foto usando javascript y laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, fileupload

Estoy intentando subir una foto y almacenarla en una ruta en especifico. Cuando en la función controller va a validar si en un campo tipo hasFile  `if ($request->hasFile($request->input('avatar')))`  no toma el campo como de tipo file y no me guarda la foto subida en la ruta especificada

Este es el código que tengo implementado:

En Blade:

```
<form id="example-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <span class="profile-picture">
                                    <input type="file" id="pic" name="avatar"/>
                                </span>

                                <div class="space-4"></div>
                                    <a onclick="change_imagen_avatar(12)" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-info">
                                        <span class="bigger-110">Aceptar</span>
                                    </a>
                                <div class="space-4"></div>
                                    <a id="cancelar_foto" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-grey">
                                        <span class="bigger-110">Cancelar</span>
                                    </a>
                            </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function change_imagen_avatar(id){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('regMiembros.change_imagen_avatar') }}',
                data: {
                    avatar: $('#id-input-file-3').val(),
                    miembro: id,

                },

                success: function (data) {

                    alert('Hola');
                    //$(location).attr('href', "{{ route('regMiembros.show', [$regMiembro->id]) }}");

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $.smkAlert({
                        text: jqXHR.responseText,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });

                }
            });
        }
```

En Controller:

```
public function change_imagen_avatar(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();

        $personas = Personas::find($input['miembro']);

        if ($request->hasFile($request->input('avatar'))) {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = $personas->nom_apellido . '.png';
            Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/uploads/hermanos/' . $filename));

            $input['avatar'] = $filename;
        }

        $personas->avatar = $input['avatar'];
        $personas->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codigo HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->

        <div>
            <div id="user-profile-1" class="user-profile row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 center">
                    <div>

                        <span id="imagen">
                            <ul class="ace-thumbnails profile-picture clearfix">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ asset('uploads/hermanos/'.$regMiembro->persona->avatar) }}"
                                       title="Miembro del Cuadro" data-rel="colorbox">
                                        <img width="200" height="200" alt="180x180"
                                             src="{{ asset('uploads/hermanos/'.$regMiembro->persona->avatar) }}"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </span>

                        <span id="imagen_oculta" style="display: none">


                            <form id="example-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <span class="profile-picture">
                                    <input type="file" id="pic" name="avatar"/>
                                </span>

                                <div class="space-4"></div>
                                    <a onclick="change_imagen_avatar({{$regMiembro->persona->id}})" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-info">
                                        <span class="bigger-110">Aceptar</span>
                                    </a>
                                <div class="space-4"></div>
                                    <a id="cancelar_foto" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-grey">
                                        <span class="bigger-110">Cancelar</span>
                                    </a>
                            </form>
                        </span>

                        <div class="space-4"></div>

                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix" id="cambiar">
                            <a id="cambiar_foto" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success">
                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-picture-o bigger-120"></i>
                                <span class="bigger-110">Cambiar Foto</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="space-6"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">

                    <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Hay varias cosas a mejorar : 
En el `controller` para verificar si el file esta presente tener que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($request->hasFile('Nombre del file')) {
    //
}
```

En el `Client` :

```
function change_imagen_avatar(id){
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('avatar', $('#id-input-file-3')[0].files[0]);
        data.append('miembro', id);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            url: '{{ route('regMiembros.change_imagen_avatar') }}',
            data: data,

            success: function (data) {

                alert('Hola');
                //$(location).attr('href', "{{ route('regMiembros.show', [$regMiembro->id]) }}");

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $.smkAlert({
                    text: jqXHR.responseText,
                    type: 'danger'
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: realice los cambios que me envió y no se envía la petición ajax, tal parece que existe algún error y no ejecuta la función, cuando quito la linea de codigo nueva que agregue enseguida funciona la petición

Comment: Que linea quitaste y te funciono ? Si podes me mostras el error y el codigo donde llamas a la funcion `change_imagen_avatar` ?

Comment: no sale ningún error, simplemente no ejecuta la peticion ajax, cuando quito

let data = new FormData();
        data.append('avatar', $('#id-input-file-3')[0].files[0]);
        data.append('miembro', id);

enseguida funciona

Comment: Si queres enviame el codigo html donde tenes el input file. Asi puedo ver si el error esta ahi. Yo lo probe recien en mi computado y me funciono

Comment: edite su respuesta y ahi lo coloque

Comment: el tema esta que formData no lo toma como una función que pueda ejecutar cuando quito new formData es que ejecuta la peticion mientras no lo hace y de igual manera no guarda la foto

Comment: Fijate 2 cosas. 1 es FormData, con la F mayucula; capaz que eso te esta fallando. Y lo segundo el selector esta de la imagen esta mal; cambia esto `$('#id-input-file-3')[0].files[0]` por esto `$('#pic')[0].files[0]`, y al final de la funcion `change_imagen_avatar` agregale un `return false` por las dudas

Answer (score 1):

tu error esta en como envias la imagen al servidor debe ser atraves de [formDAta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData).

tambien debes agregar el [csrf_token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf) ya sea en tu form o en tu meta en este ejemplo usaremos el meta agregado en el head del documento! por si tu js es externo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

o agregarlo a la peticion ajax como cabecera:

```
  function change_imagen_avatar(id){
            let _CSRF = { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') };
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('miembro', id);
            formData.append('avatar', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                headers: _CSRF,
                url: '{{ route('regMiembros.change_imagen_avatar') }}',
                data: formData,

                success: function (data) {

                    alert('Hola');
                    //$(location).attr('href', "{{ route('regMiembros.show', [$regMiembro->id]) }}");

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $.smkAlert({
                        text: jqXHR.responseText,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Necesito pasar un id como se lo paso al formData, gracias de antemano

Comment: solo debes hacer un `data.append("id",id);` igual ya lo corregi!

Comment: realice los cambios que me envió y no se envía la petición ajax, tal parece que existe algún error y no ejecuta la función, cuando lo quito lo nuevo que adicione enseguida funciona la función

Comment: intenta ahora a ver es que no se llama id si no miembro!

Comment: sigue igual no se ejecuta la peticion ajax, pero cuando quito 

´var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('miembro', id);
                formData.append('avatar', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);´

funciona al instante

Comment: te marca algun tipo de error o algo?

Comment: no marca ningun tipo de error, simplemente no envia la peticion, es como si no reconociera el formData y no ejecuta lo demas, en cuanto quito esas lineas al momeno funciona

Comment: el tema esta  que formData no lo toma como una función que pueda ejecutar cuando quito new formData es que ejecuta la peticion mientras no lo hace y de igual manera no guarda la foto

Comment: que navegador estas utilizando que no reconoce `new formData;` si esta soportado por casi todos! [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData#AutoCompatibilityTable)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89029/discussion-between-bryro-and-albertolg89).